# Specific MySQL Normalization for many same inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Thank you for opening this post. I need your help with MySQL DB Normalization.
I have 10 sales people, selling stuff, and I have few people in support team, that does telemarketing sales for salesmen. So anyways, was thinking what's the best way to normalize table, but to take into consideration that salesmen often quits so I have to transfer their DB to another sales agent DB.

Currently I have only one table. Is it better to put all stuff into that one table or to separate into many other small tables. Currently my table looks like this

id , mb , company_name , city , company_owner , phone_no1 , phone_no2 , app_status , sales_agent , cc_agent , three_options , exp_date , cc_comment , sales_comment , input_date , call_made , status

id = AI PK UQ

mb = is unique key that I provide

company_name, city, company_owner, cc_comment, sales_comment, input_date, call_made, phone_no1 and phone_no2 should be in one table since it's all different. Right?

```
sales_agent = I have 10 people
cc_agent = I have 3 people
app_status = I have 3 statuses to select, so it has to be one out of three
status = I have 15 statuses to pick from, it has to be only one of those
```

So, maybe one table for all changeable stuff, another for sales_agent, another for cc_agent, app_status and status?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of smaller tables is better.  The goal of normalization is to eliminate repeating data, and increase referential integrity.  You achieve that with lots of small tables and use of foreign keys.

When creating your table structure, you want to look for nouns.  When you use a noun-phrase approach, identifying possible tables is easier.  In your case, I see columns called company_name, company_owner, etc.  Create a table called 'Company' and give it columns id, name, owner, city, state, zip etc.

You have sales people, agents, and support people.  But they are all employees.  So another possible table is 'Employee' and job_title is a column.

Really spend the time and think out the database structure, and try to get the database into [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).